# Get json array and store it in DB as string

Tags: arrays, json, string, jaxb, persistence

I have a rest resource that receives json like this:

```
{
"id":"MyHotel”,
properties:[
    {"id": "location",
     "value":"downtown"},
    {"id": "free wi-fi",
     "value": "yes"}]
}
```

which generally can be represented by java code as

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "loginMethod")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Hotel{
@XmlElement(name="id", required="true")
private String id;
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "properties", required = true)
    @XmlElement(name = "property")
    private List<HotelProperties> properties;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "properties")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class HotelProperties{
    @XmlElement(name = "id", required = true)
    private String id;
    @XmlElement(name = "value", required = true)
    private String value;
}
```

However I only store this information and provide it to other service on-demand so that I do not want to deal with the List in database.
I'd prefer to store the id of Hotel in one column and the entire JsonArray containing the properties in another column - without any parsing as a String. So that my JPA entity will look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="HOTELS")
public class HotelEntity{
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "properties", nullable = false)
    private String properties;
}
```

Looks like something very obvious but I don't understand how to do this and cannot find something like this in internet. Your opinion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options:
Simplest option just to create a string:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("list",myHotel.getProperties());
hotelEntity.setProperties(obj.toString);
```

More comprehensive - back and forth using Jackson

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
hotelEntity.setProperties(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myHotel.getProperties()));
List<HotelProperties>=new ArrayList<HotelProperties>();
props=objectMapper.readValue(myHotel.getProperties(),new TypeReference<ArrayList<HotelProperties>>() {});
```